# how to obtain the days where the sum of the values is greater than 420 in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo, crud

I'm trying to sum the 'emsion_co2' values by day. in order to know in what days the value is higher than 420, but my query is not working.

this is the database

```
 db.test_sensores.insert([{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:00:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":16.61,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":83.74,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:00:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":1.572,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00188,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:15:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":15.75,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":83.08,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:15:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":1.626,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00146,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-10T00:30:00Z","dia":10,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":14.08,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":90.05,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-10T00:30:00Z","dia":10,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":1.614,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00173,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:45:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":10.62,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":92.27,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:45:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":1,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":1.59,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00196,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:00:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":22.08,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":34.92,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:00:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":2.055,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00269,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:15:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":21.12,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":37.7,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:15:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":2.102,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00272,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-10T00:30:00Z","dia":10,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":24.26,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":52.52,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-10T00:30:00Z","dia":10,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":2.023,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00255,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:45:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":1,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Temperatura","valor":24.51,"unidad":"ºC"},{"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa","valor":34.1,"unidad":"%"}]},
{"timestamp":"2020-07-01T00:45:00Z","dia":01,"sensor_id":2,"location_id":2,"medidas":[{"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","valor":1.957,"unidad":"gCO2/m2"},{"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico","valor":0.00215,"unidad":"kWh/m2"}]}])
```

And the next query is what I was trying, but the result is wrong because there is not showing the sum, just appear in 0 the values.

```
db.test_sensores.aggregate([{$match:{'medidas.tipo_medida':'Emision_CO2'}},{$group:{_id:'$dia', acumulado_emisiones_CO2:{$sum:'$medidas.0.valor'}}}])
```

In my query is missing how to find the days where emision_co2 value > 420 too, I was thinking manually but if there is an automated way, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason why you group by `dia` field?

Answer (score 1):

Unsure why you attempt to group by `dia`,

1. `$match`
2. `$set` - Set `timestamp` to Date object, `medidas_Emision_CO2_valor` for sum all the values in `medidas` array by filtering (`$filter`) the document with `tipo_medida` is "Emision_CO2" via `$reduce`.
3. `$group` - Group by date, month, and year of `timestamp` and sum the `medidas_Emision_CO2_valor` values as `acumulado_emisiones_CO2`.
4. `$match` - Filter the documents with `acumulado_emisiones_CO2` is greater than (`$gt`) 420.

```
db.test_sensores.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "medidas.tipo_medida": "Emision_CO2"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      timestamp: {
        $toDate: "$timestamp"
      },
      medidas_Emision_CO2_valor: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$medidas",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.tipo_medida",
                  "Emision_CO2"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.valor"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        day: {
          "$dayOfMonth": "$timestamp"
        },
        month: {
          "$month": "$timestamp"
        },
        year: {
          $year: "$timestamp"
        }
      },
      acumulado_emisiones_CO2: {
        $sum: "$medidas_Emision_CO2_valor"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "acumulado_emisiones_CO2_valor": {
        $gt: 420
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZEg6P9sxJXE)